# Visa on expired passport

Tags: visas, passport-renewals, delta-air-lines

If your visa is on an expired passport but still valid, can you still use it with your new passport, or does the old passport have to have a recent expiration date? If so, how do you transfer your visa to your new passport?

Answer (score 17):

The answer to this question depends on the country that issued the visa. There are two general situations:

- The visa in your old passport is accepted in conjunction with a current passport. You need to bring both passports but no other action is required.

  Example: [Will my Chinese visa still be valid if I renew my passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44687/will-my-chinese-visa-still-be-valid-if-i-renew-my-passport)
- The country that issued the visa requires that the visa be in a current passport. In this case they will offer a service that transfers your old visa to the new passport (they will print a new sticker and affix it to the new passport, and do something like punch a hole through the old one to invalidate it).

  Example: [(New Zealand) Transferring my visa to a new passport](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/transferring-my-visa-to-a-new-passport)