# My old passport was damaged, I got new one

Tags: visas, damaged-passports

My old Indian passport was damaged in water so I applied new passport. I got a new passport but it’s without stamps and on my old passport they mentioned (passport cancelled.visa if any valid) what does the meaning of this. I have to apply for stamps or I can travel with old and new passport.

Comment: Related: [Visa on expired passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112004/visa-on-expired-passport).